# How to insert values to table where one column needs a single value from select statement and another column needs multiple values from another select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, insert-select

Table1 product: productname , productID

Table2 alias: product_alias, components, id

Table3 mapping:  productId, alias_component_id

`` INSERT INTO `mapping`(`productId`,`alias_component_id`)  VALUES ((SELECT productID FROM product WHERE NAME='abc'),  (SELECT id FROM alias WHERE product_alias='xyz')); ``

The first select would return single value while second select would return multiple values. Basically, for single productId, I want to loop through and insert multiple alias ids. I am getting **Subquery returns more than 1 row** error

Tried `` INSERT INTO `mapping`(`alias_component_id`) (SELECT id FROM alias WHERE product_alias='xyz')) ``
but this would leave productID column null.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `mapping`(`productId`,`alias_component_id`)  
SELECT p.productID, a.id
FROM product p 
CROSS JOIN alias a 
WHERE p.name = 'abc' AND a.product_alias = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Yeah this make sense. I never though of join unrelated tables. This works :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert with `VALUES` part, but [with `SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html). In this select you join your tables on the logic you need.

Comment: Yeah i tried insert select, but did not think of joining those tables. Thanks